# multipartのrequestsについてなのです

Tags: python

```
POST /v2/users/create HTTP/1.1
Host: mixch.tv
Connection: keep-alive
X-Mixch-Country: jp
X-Mixch-Attribution: Organic
Accept: */*
X-Mixch-AdvertisingId: A29428C7-8C02-419F-A071-E47E3DA184A9
User-Agent: mixch/5.2.1 (iPhone; iOS 10.2; Scale/2.00)
Accept-Language: ja-JP;q=1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 262033
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+EF9D031E6AE26D0E

--Boundary+EF9D031E6AE26D0E
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_year"

-1
--Boundary+EF9D031E6AE26D0E
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nickname"

Hi
--Boundary+EF9D031E6AE26D0E
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="prefecture"

-1
--Boundary+EF9D031E6AE26D0E
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.png"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

����
```

これのmultipartのリクエストの送信の仕方を教えてください...
Python2でお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

マニュアルにそのまんまのmultipartの例がありますよ。
http://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

```
import requests


data = dict(
    birth_year=-1,
    nickname="Hi",
    prefecture=-1,
)

files = dict(
    file=open('xxx.png', 'rb')
)

r = requests.post('http://localhost:8888', files=files, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

別のターミナルで`nc -l 8888`として実行すると、次の内容がPOSTされていることがわかります。BoundaryのIDは実行時に決まるランダムな文字列なので、値をきにする必要はありません。

```
$ nc -l 8888
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 420
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=177b060d764643c398b667b5841c06df

--177b060d764643c398b667b5841c06df
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_year"

-1
--177b060d764643c398b667b5841c06df
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nickname"

Hi
--177b060d764643c398b667b5841c06df
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="prefecture"

-1
--177b060d764643c398b667b5841c06df
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="xxx.png"


--177b060d764643c398b667b5841c06df--
```